# Upload public object to Google Cloud Storage with public link

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-api-client

I've searched everywhere on this but I cannot find a solution, how can I upload a public object to my google cloud storage, I want to have it so once the image is uploaded it can be viewed by anyone in the world.

It seems I can only get this done if I manually click the public link in google storage, but I want to have it so I can automatically make these objects public through googles api . [image]

Comment: This post may help you. Good luck!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417893/setting-an-object-to-shared-public-url-when-inserting-into-google-cloud-storage?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The web interface doesn't provide a way to make the objects being uploaded public automatically, but you can do one of two things:

1. If you want to just make objects publicly readable during one particular session you could use gsutil to do it, e.g.,

   gsutil -m cp -a public-read dir/* gs://your-bucket
2. If you want to make objects publicly readable across all future sessions you could set a default object ACL on the bucket, using a command like:

   gsutil defacl set public-read gs://your-bucket

If you do that, uploads via the web interface (as well as by any other API requests, e.g., gsutil cp commands) will be made publicly readable automatically.

Comment: does that apply to the entire directory, is that just a one time use or once that is set on the directory all objects loaded after will be public-read?

Comment: The command is copying all the files in 'dir', and uploading it to 'your-bucket' with each individual file being public-read.

If you want to upload more files, you have to mark them "public-read" as well.

I also recommend using the -m flag if you are uploading multiple files at once.

Comment: @SandeepDinesh Thanks for the clarification, I was unsure exactly how it was being used. I understand fully now and was able to resolve my issue.

Comment: I added setting a default object ACL on the bucket to my answer, since that provides a way to do it that would work with the web interface.