# gae, ferris, python, cloud-storage - image upload, how to activate public link for image?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'd like to know to ensure that the cloud storage link is public. How can I do this through the ferris framework? Uploading works, but I want to make sure the link is public.

I'm following this documentation for uploading an image via webrowser with the ferris framework:

http://ferris-framework.appspot.com/docs/users_guide/uploads_and_downloads.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using the gsutil and making the entire bucket public after reading this post: [Upload public object to Google Cloud Storage with public link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867160/upload-public-object-to-google-cloud-storage-with-public-link/31867400#comment53704806_31867400)